# How to popUntil to a named route in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a *signin_screen.dart* which after taking the user's email and password, checks for a stream of authStateChanges. If the login is successful it takes automatically takes the user to the account screen (which a named route: "/my-account"). I'm trying to display a CircularProgressIndiciator in a showDialog for the time between the user submitting his details by clicking on the sign in button till the time the login process is completed.

**My Code**:

*signin_screen.dart*

```
return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const AccountScreen(); //named-route of "/my-account"
            } else {
              return CustomLoginWidget();
}
```

The following function is called when the sign in button (implemented in the CustomLoginWidget) is clicked :

```
void signInUser() async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) {
         return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
       });

    context.read<FirebaseAuthMethods>().loginWithEmail(
        email: _emailController.text.trim(),
        password: _passwordController.text.trim(),
        context: context);

    navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    //Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/my-account"));
  }
```

**Note**:

Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/my-account")); does not work.

```
navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
```

has been added as a property in MaterialApp(), where `navigatorKey` has been declared as `final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();`

**Issue Faced**:

If I do `navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst` it takes the app to the splash screen (as named by the "/" route), **but I want the app to load the account_screen under the route name:** ***"/my-account"***.

Is there a way to implement this? I have tried route.isCurrent and route.isActive, but to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: have you tried navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/my-account")); ?

Comment: Try using navigagtorKey.currentState!.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/my-account", (route) => false)

Comment: @suzan thsi doesn't work.

Comment: @xaer this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about try to declare a route name for your MyAccount class

static const routeName = "/my-account"
and then try this

```
navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == MyAccount.routeName);
```

Comment: I did try this, but i didn't work either.